# android R class dont recognize the raw folder

Tags: android, eclipse, development-environment, r.java-file

Hi i want to play an mp3 backround music , i create the res\raw folder and put there an mp3 file and every thing is ok but: 
when i want to make an mediaplayer object R dont recognize my raw folder . 
I tryed to clean the project and reopen eclipse 
thanks for all the helpers :)
here is the mainactivity:

```
    package com.example.whatsflagitis;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaPlayer mysong=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.)
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `R.raw.mp3FileName`?

Comment: Yep R dont recognized the raw folder ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below steps to resolve the issue,It worked for me:

1. Cleaning the project and then building it again.
2. Closing project and then opening it again.
3. Going to Project Properties > Java Build Path > Tick Android Version Checkbox
4. ensure no errors in XML files,Because errors in xml file Prevents the R.jave file to be created.
5. try downloading the latest version of android SDK,if available.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you will want to change the last line of onCreate to:

```
MediaPlayer mysong=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.filename);
```

(note the changes to the second parameter and the addition of the semicolon)

then right after that put:

```
mysong.start();
```

That should at least get it so it plays right as your app starts up.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to rebuild your project after creating /raw folder and it should work

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem of **raw folder** not getting recognized.

My observations:

1. My file (Image) name was starting with a capital letter **'A'**.
2. That was the only file in the raw folder. (If other files with small letters as starting were there then **raw** might have got recognized.)

Corrections Done:

1. Changed that capital 'A' with 'a' in the file name.

Now it worked and the **R.raw.fileName** came with no errors with raw folder being recognized!

P.S.: It was a hit and trial method for me hope it works for you too.